# python map vs list comprehsnion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return the min and max of a string of numbers, ie. ("1 2 3 4 5 6")

The code that I came up with is as follows

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split(' ')
    map(int, numbers)
    return str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers))
```

This code does not work for the following example:

```
print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
6 -214
```

However, a similar function crafted as:

```
def min_and_max(numbers):
    nn = [int(s) for s in numbers.split(' ')]
    return "%i %i" % (max(nn),min(nn))
```

Returns the correct answer

```
print(min_and_max("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
542 -214
```

Shouldn't

```
map(int, numbers)
```

be the same as

```
[int(number) for number in numbers]
```

Why do the two functions not return the same values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `high_and_low` method, `map(int, numbers)` is not being assigned to a value.

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split(' ')
    numbers = map(int, numbers)
    return str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers))
```

Also, `map` returns an `iterator` in Python 3.x. Your `min(numbers)` will error because `max` will exhaust the `iterator` and throw a `ValueError` due to an empty sequence. So you need to convert it to a `list`

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split(' ')
    numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
    return str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers))
```

Comment: `map(int, numbers)` is equivalent to `(int(s) for s in numbers)`. `[int(s) for s in numbers]` is the equivalent of `list(int(s) for s in numbers)`

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it needs to be converted to a list!

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't because you don't assign the result of `map` anywhere so `min` and `max` use `numbers` from `numbers.split(' ')`. That is, you're using string comparisons.

The list comprehension is saved to `nn` and that is the name that is used in `min` and `max`.

Despite that, even if you *did* save numbers as the result of `map`:

```
numbers = map(int, numbers)
```

you'd still get an error since `max` will first consume the iterable (until it's exhausted) and then `min` will complain because it'll receive an empty iterable.

You'd probably need to use something like `itertools.tee`, supply both `min` and `max` with `map(int, numbers)` or use a list-comprehension as you've already done.

Comment: Right, I did notice that when saved to a variable min() gave an error, therefore I thought map would work in place. Can you explain why adding         v = map(int, numbers)
    b = list(filter(None.__ne__, v))
resolves this issue?

Comment: You can ignore this comment as it was explained by @Wondercricket above.

Comment: Where did you come up with that `filter`? Either way, lists can be iterated through many times, the result of `map` only once. If you need to go through a sequence more than once, use a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do the two functions not return the same values?

Because the function you involve in map does not work in place.

when you write

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    numbers = numbers.split(' ')
    map(int, numbers)    ## DOES NOT WORK IN PLACE
    ## So ADD THE LINE BELOW
    numbers = map(int, numbers)    
    return str(max(numbers)) + ' ' + str(min(numbers))
```

you must somewhere reassign `numbers` like so

```
numbers = map(int, numbers)
```

Comment: Please see @Wondercricket answer above, as the code you listed errors on max().

Comment: @Brian. Interesting. Actually, i am using python27, in which `map` still returns a list. That is why i did not get it. I should have.

Comment: I'm trying to make the transition from 2.7 to 3.6 as well, which is why I forgot map no longer returns a list.